# getenv - how to set environment variable

Tags: c++, linux, environment-variables, getenv

I set environment variable this way:

```
export MY_DIR="$HOME/projects"
```

Then I want to read that variable in my program:

```
char *name = getenv("MY_DIR");
```

but I get a null value, **Edit 1:** when I run the program using Qt Creator.

When I compile:

```
g++ myprogram.cpp -o myprogram
```

and run:

```
./myprogram
```

the program form a terminal I get correct variable.

Comment: How do you invoke your program?

Comment: Could you be a bit more elaborate? Because this will code will work and is working on my machine.

Comment: `export` does *not* set a variable for the whole system, although it's a common misconception among novices.

Comment: If you export your variable from one terminal and trying to get it into other terminal then it wont work instead export your variable from /etc/profile

Comment: You need to figure out how to set the environment for the program launched by Qt Creator.  NetBeans definitely has this, QtC probably does too.

Answer (score 0):

At the left tab you can click at 'Projects', which will show you some options. At the "Build & Run' tab, click the 'Run' button below, then search for "Run Environment". Open it's details and there you can add or edit variables that will be available while your program is running.

[image]